# Finding the last command issued by a blocking process

Tags: sql-server, locking

I've developed an interface from `ERP SAP Business One` to warehouse management, and am facing problems concerning database locks. My program includes direct write operations into the `ERP` database (a user defined field is filled during asynchronous event processing after creating or changing a sales order). It is suspected to be responsible for blocking situations occurring quite often each day.

When a blocking situation occurs, `sp_who2` gives me information about blocking and blocked processes, every time pointing to an `spid` used by the `BPM` management software as the "root blocking process". The status of this `spid` is always shown as "sleeping".

1. Can a "sleeping" process cause a database lock for other processes, e.g. when transactions weren't committed?
2. How can I find out the last command of the sleeping process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**2) How can I find out the last command of the sleeping process?**

You can use Adam Machanic's [sp_whoisActive](http://whoisactive.com) tool to find the [lead blocker](http://web.archive.org/web/20110425104932/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/04/23/leader-of-the-block-a-month-of-activity-monitoring-part-23-of-30.aspx).

You can also use DMV's (starting sql 2005 and up) to find out what the spid was executing :

```
-- You can use "most_recent_sql_handle" in sys.dm_exec_connections to see the last statement that was executed.    
SELECT  c.session_id, t.text,
            QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.objectid, t.dbid)) + '.'
            + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.objectid, t.dbid)) proc_name,
            c.connect_time,
            s.last_request_start_time,
            s.last_request_end_time,
            s.status
    FROM    sys.dm_exec_connections c
    JOIN    sys.dm_exec_sessions s
            ON c.session_id = s.session_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle) t
    WHERE   c.session_id = -- spid for the spid involved in blocking

-- for any OPEN Transactions, you can use `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions` and `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`

SELECT  st.transaction_id,
        at.name,
        at.transaction_begin_time,
        at.transaction_state,
        at.transaction_status
FROM    sys.dm_tran_session_transactions st
JOIN    sys.dm_tran_active_transactions at
        ON st.transaction_id = at.transaction_id
 WHERE   st.session_id = -- spid for the spid involved in blocking
```

Refer to :

- [Understanding and resolving SQL Server blocking problems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224453)
- [Different Status of a SPID in SQL Server and What do they mean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlsakthi/different-status-of-a-spid-in-sql-server-and-what-do-they-mean)
- [Locking in Microsoft SQL Server (Part 4 – How to detect blocking)](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2011/05/26/locking-in-microsoft-sql-server-part-4-how-to-detect-blocking/)

Alternatively, you can use a mix of [Event Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190427.aspx) or Profiler with [Blocked process report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191168.aspx) to detect blocking on your database server.

Answer (score 3):

Using the SPID of the sleeping process:

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER (<spid>)
```

This will give you the last input string that was executed by that session.

Now technically, that's not necessarily the last *SQL Statement* executed, because if the input command did something like call a stored procedure, then there could be a lot of SQL Statements inside of the one *input command*.  So, if you need the last/current *SQL Statement* instead, then let me know as there's a slightly more complicated way to get that.